# File name contains # caused Spring Batch StaxEventItemReader failed to open

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-batch

I have an input file with # in the name (UPX#L.xxxxx001.xml). Spring Batch StaxEventItemReader failed to open this file. Is there anyway to escape this special character?  Please advise.

This is my bean

```
 <bean id="myItemReader" parent="myItemReaderParent" scope="step">

        <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['toolf.input.file.name']}"/>

 </bean>

<bean id="myItemReaderParent" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader" scope="prototype">

    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="MyRec"/>

    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="myUnmarshaller"/>

</bean>
```

```
[INFO ]org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1[2015-02-05 10:27:23,487] - Sending notification for start of JobExecution: id=52760, version=1, startTime=Thu Feb 05 10:27:23 EST
 2015, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Thu Feb 05 10:27:23 EST 2015, status=STARTED, exitStatus=exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=52759, version=0, JobParameters=[

{toolf.institutionSymbol=YDX , toolf.projectId=013832, toolf.orderId=678161, toolf.transmissionDate=20150205 10:27:23.392 EST, toolf.input.file.name=/batchdata/dataload/xxx/in/tool/UPX#L.xxxxx001.xml, toolf.out.root.directory=/batchdata/output, toolf.out.input.file.name.without.path=YDX.013832.678161.YbpUsSI#Picklists.d20150204.t140001.xml, toolf.out.working.directory/batchdata/dataload/xxx/in/tool/, timestamp=1423150043392}

], Job=[timeOfOrderLabelJob]]
[INFO ]org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1[2015-02-05 10:27:23,576] - Executing step: [toolPrologue]
[ERROR]org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1[2015-02-05 10:27:23,607] - Encountered an error executing the step
 org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
 at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:137)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor260.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
 at $Proxy9.open(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:93)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:301)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:192)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
 at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:129)
 at org.oclc.tool.mule.launch.MuleJobLauncher.launchJob(MuleJobLauncher.groovy:74)
 at org.oclc.tool.mule.launch.JobLauncher$launchJob.call(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
 at org.oclc.tool.mule.si.JmsMessageUnwrapper.unwrapMessage(JmsMessageUnwrapper.groovy:42)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor596.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:83)
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:102)
 at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
 at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:225)
 at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:125)
 at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
 at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:64)
 at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:98)
 at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
 at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:110)
 at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
 at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:61)
 at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
 at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
 at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
 at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(MessagingTemplate.java:189)
 at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:183)
 at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.send(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:424)
 at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:278)
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:535)
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:495)
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doOpen(StaxEventItemReader.java:182)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
 ... 73 more
[INFO ]org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1[2015-02-05 10:27:23,612] - enter DetailLogStepExecutionListener.afterStep
[INFO ]org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1[2015-02-05 10:27:23,612] - exit DetailLogStepExecutionListener.afterStep
```

Comment: How do you the problem is `#`? Error is "Input resource must exist".

Comment: Yes. It is the # problem. Once the # is removed it works fine.

Comment: I think you can use spEL in a way like<br/>

`<property name="resource" value="#{T(java.lang.URI).create("file:{jobParameters['toolf.input.file.name']}").toURL()}"/>`<br/>

Answer (score 5):

In a [URL/URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), the `#` character is reserved, used to delimit the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (which would have no meaning to the `file:` resource scheme).  If you want to include this character as part of the path, it must be escaped with `%23`

Rather than concatenate your value to `file:` in your bean definition file, I recommend that you specify the parameter as a full URI/URI, rather than a filesystem path:

```
<property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['toolf.input.file.url']}"/>
```

And set `toolf.input.file.url` to:

```
file:/batchdata/dataload/xxx/in/tool/UPX%23L.xxxxx001.xml
```

This will avoid any other escapement pitfalls you might encounter, like with characters `@`, `!`, `=`, etc.

If you *must* use a filesystem path as a parameter, you should be able to use:

```
<property name="resource" value="#{new java.io.File(jobParameters['toolf.input.file.name']).toURI().toURL()}"/>
```

Comment: if (fileName.contains("#")) {              def (value1, value2) = fileName.split("#")              fileName = value1 + "%23#" + value2          } I tried this. Still doesn't work

Comment: Should be "%23" and not "%23#"

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your error message and the responses, your problem is clear, both Tunaki and Glenn Lane are partially correct, and I'm up-voting Glenn Lane for answering the question you asked, and doing it well.

From your reply to Glenn:

> *if (fileName.contains("#")) { def (value1, value2) = fileName.split("#") fileName = value1 + "%23#" + value2 } I tried this. Still doesn't work*

Escaping will not help the situation.

The character is already being handled somewhere along the execution chain, Tunaki was correct in questioning the type error you were having.

From your error log:

> [ERROR]org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-1[2015-02-05 10:27:23,607] - Encountered an error executing the step
>    org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader

Coupled with the resource state exception Tunaki pointed out, we can conclude that is the case. There is insufficient information here to say why or where this occurring, but here are a two general categories:

1. Depending on how it's arriving at, or from, the file store the character may already removed from the file at that point in the process or aliased on the Store in a way the File handler can't deal with. For the reasons Glenn pointed out.
2. Depending on the Message or Job Handling in your execution chain it is being stripped out as it transformed into or out of a URI/URL call. For the reasons Glenn pointed out.

> Yes. It is the # problem. Once the # is removed it works fine.

Based on the above statement the simple, quick, and dirty solution would be to be aware of this and handle it by stripping and injecting the # directly from the file or uri as needed. Based on your code snippet, you know how to do this.

The correct way to solve this would be to track down where the resource error is occurring and ensure that your file handling is consistent across the entire Job flow.

Without all the right code here and/or knowing more about your system configuration I can't be specific. There is simply not enough information between the bean and the error log to say exactly where this occurring only that this is exactly your problem.

Here are some possible suggestions:

I am assuming you've checked the file Store directly and hand removed the # and changed the file name in the job and it runs, based on your above statement.

1. Try to access the file on the store from a different java object using the same identifier and it works; Then check how your item reader implementation is handling the file access.
2. If it failed or that is not the failure point. Check that "#" value is the job file and if it's there and/or the only # when you perform the split.
3. If that all checks find out how it is arriving to the file store and that resource can be properly located in the store and that # is not also reserved in your implementation or requires special handling/configuration.

This will help narrow done the root cause.